# Looking for a highly customizable library for image carousel

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I know these types of "questions" are discouraged but since I have quite specific needs I believe this question does have a definitive answer.

I need an image carousel that meets the following requirements:

- I can make my own transitions (basically I want to apply a class and have a CSS transition)
- Mobile support with swipe
- My own markup if possible
- Manual switching as well as automatic switching

Is there any library like this out there?
I've tried [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) but it doesn't allow me to have my own transitions.

Maybe I'm better off just using [Swipe JS](http://swipejs.com/) and writing my own transitions, though there are many edge cases to be aware of so I'd rather not do this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom built version for desktop and SwipeJS for touch devices.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Cycle is a very good plug in that mostly does what you want.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

You can use any of the default transitions or create your own named ones in the options.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv2.html